# How to know in JavaScript if an event name is custom?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I know if an event is a DOM/HTML Event in JavaScript ?

Let say, I have an element `<a>`. How can I know that `click` or `focus` are native events but another like `mycustomevent` isn't?

For example, if I want to attach the listener in a different way if the event is  native or custom:

```
var eventName; // can be 'foo', 'click' or 'touchstart';

var link = document.querySelector('a');
if(//custom){
    eventName += '.domain';
}
link.addEventListener(eventName, function (){ //... });
```

Comment: You can read documentation.

Comment: Inspecting whether the event exists on the prototype will give you distinction between a newly assigned event and a prototype event... (of course you or someone may have altered the prototype itself; which would render that method useless.)

Comment: What is `attachEventListener`?

Comment: Add a var in your custom event and check if this var exists.. every nativ event shouldn't have this var.

Comment: @Justinas yes, I can but the goal here is to do it dynamically

Comment: @torazaburo it is a typo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function isNativeEvent(eventname) {
    return typeof document.body["on" + eventname] !== "undefined";
}
```

This will check if the event handler is defined on some element (including being `null`), which means it's a native event.

```
> isNativeEvent('click')
< true
> isNativeEvent('myCustomEvent')
< false
```

Comment: Yes, but I'm wondering if all events have the property on the node, for examples `touchstart`, see http://jsbin.com/giraxotiki/1/edit?html,js,console

Comment: If event is registered in jQuery, but not registered in JS, than this function returns true, but that event is not native JS event

Comment: It seems this is the method jQuery use (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L250)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript native events are listed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events, so if the event you use is not among the list, it's a custom event.